# media queries: sending an image from the top to the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get an image to go from my header to my footer or something similar when the window is below 400px

I don't have any code to show, I have researched this for hours to no avail.

Is this possible? I'm using bootstrap for responsive purposes.

Comment: This would often be done by having the image appear on the page twice, the header image hidden under 400px, the footer image hidden at 401px and above with @media queries.

Comment: There was a comment here before, its been deleted, it did work so i wonder why it was deleted.

Comment: using flexboxes order property is easy...

Comment: can you give us a very simple html structure of your page?

Comment: Why not have an image in both positions and just hide/show on certain media queries? via display: none;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with just CSS, whether or not you're using Bootstrap. Keeping with mobile first, I solved this so that the header starts at the footer and moves to the top when the window is wider than 400px. I made [a demo for you](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Qwazwd).

Say your HTML looks like this (I used an H1 instead of an IMG tag):

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="header"><h1>header image</h1></div>
    <div class="content">Here's some content</div>
    <div class="footer">Some footer stuff</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Your CSS should look like this:

```
body {
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    background: white;
}

h1 {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    font-size:2em;
    height:2em;
    background: gray;
}

@media (min-width:400px) {

    h1 {
        position: relative;
    }

    .content {
        margin-top: 2em;
    }

}
```

Comment: Glad that worked for you, @red_starz! When you have a moment, please "accept" my answer as the one you used. Thanks!